# If no data is coming, the div should not appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Sometimes the data may not come from the backend. I don't want to show div when data is not coming. how can I do it?

```
<div className="policydetailinformation__item">
 <h3>{t('policy.policy-details.address')}</h3>
 <p>{props.location.state.policy.information}</p>
</div>
```

I tried to put "ngIf" and got an error like this: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for 'div'.

Comment: Just put a conditional statement on it, if the data is passed through, show it, if not, don't?

Comment: You can use conditional render with a check if the data is present, we show that div
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a conditional class

```
<div className={youdata===null?"hidden":"policydetailinformation__item"}>
 <h3>{t('policy.policy-details.address')}</h3>
 <p>{props.location.state.policy.information}</p>
</div>
```

give a hidden class a display none property

Answer (score 0):

Set the condition and `&&` then your `div`

```
{showDiv && <div>
....
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
  const addr =  t('policy.policy-details.address');
  const isData = !!addr
  return addr ? (
    <div className="policydetailinformation__item">
     <h3>{addr}</h3>
     <p>{props.location.state.policy.information}</p>
    </div>
  ) : null
}
```